# Count how many times a value is exceeded in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

in a Python list, I need to count how many times a value is exceeded.

This code counts how many values exceed a limit.
Suppose I have this example, and I want to count how many time `2` is exceeded.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
a = pd.Series(array)
print(len(a[a >= 2]))
# prints 5
```

How can I *collapse consecutive values*, such that `2` is returned instead?

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: If you want to collapse consecutive values that are >=2, I think you're going to have to iterate through the list yourself, I doubt you will find a function that will do it for you.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of @Siha, but I thought I'd ask

Comment: @Djib2001 I'd like to return 2, instead of 5

Comment: @tsigalko18 why 2? Do you want to find the number of unique values in `a` larger than 2? I don't understand what you mean by *collapse*.

Comment: By collapse, I mean that each sublist `[2, 3, 4]` and `[2, 3]` should be considered only once in the counting

Comment: When you remove the 'greater than' sign (>), doesn't that return 2?

Comment: That might work @shiv_90 (you mean ==), thanks. I have to check in the general case

Comment: Yes @tsigalko18. `==` sign and maybe even consider removing the duplicates, if you want to know how many numbers actually exceed 2 rather than knowing the exact times 2 is exceeded by repeated numbers.

Answer (score 6):

First compute `exc = a.ge(2)` - a Series answering the question:
*Does the current value is >= 2*.

Then, to get a number of **sequences** of "exceeding" elements, run:

```
result = (exc.shift().ne(exc) & exc).sum()
```

The result for your data is just *2*.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Note to OP: You can either shift left or right and have a different behavior concerning first and last values exceeding threshold.

Comment: This is the most robust solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are very close.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> b = a >= 2 
>>> b
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Now, instead of counting `True`s, you need to count how many times you see `False, True`. you can compare each item in b to the item before it, `b[i] > b[i-1]`, to find `False, True`s. and you need to consider the start of the array `a` as well.

```
>>> c = np.r_[ b[0], b[1:] > b[:-1] ]
>>> c
array([ False, True, False, False, False,  True, False, False])
>>> np.sum( c )
2
```

where

```
>>> b[1:] 
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
>>> b[:-1]
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

Comment: The OP knows this. He wants a way to eliminate consecutive values exceeding threshold.

Comment: @Tarik FWIW, I think this is exactly what OP wants and it's basically the same approach as yours. using `c = ~b[:-1] & b[1:]` might be a bit more readable, though. And generally explaining a little more why it works would also be good :)

Comment: @Tarik I don't think so, the question simply asks how to get the count. you can also check the OP's comment on the post.

Comment: @swenzel, thank you for your comment, I'll add a little more explanation.

Comment: This seems to work in the general case, but I agree it needs a bit more explanation. For completeness, this code snippet assumes the first values being < 2 though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to remove duplicates before converting it to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1]
arr_set = set(array)

a = pd.Series(list(arr_set))
print(len(a[a >= 2]))
```

You can also do this with numpy by only showing unique values and then filtering.

```
len(a.unique()[a.unique() >= 2])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I can't rely on having duplicate/unique values, which I agree would be much simpler :(

Comment: Does not answer OP question.

Comment: @tsigalko18 Why not? You can certainly rely on removing duplicates and then returning the times a value is exceeded.